# OST Song at 17:00 Fairy Tail Episode 189

Tags: music, fairy-tail

Anyone know that name of the song played at 17:00 of E189 where Sting is facing the 5 Fairy Tail in the Grand Magic Games?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, found it in the first volume of the Original Sound Collection: 19. Fairy Tail Rises.

https://soundcloud.com/fairy-tail-2014-ost/fairy-tail-2014-ost-19-fairy